# How Can I Code This So The Player Won't Start Automatically?

Tags: html, embed, mp3, autostart

This is what I have the bottom of the page.

```
<BR>
<BR>

    <table width=145 border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5">Mp3 Control Console</font></td></tr>
      <tr><td><EMBED SRC="https://www.fanficparadise.com/Music/mp3/Hiru_no_Tsuki.mp3" AUTOSTART="FALSE" controls="smallconsole" width=295 height=45></embed></td></tr>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5">Hiru_no_Tsuki.mp3 from Outlaw Star</font></td></tr>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5"><a href="https://www.fanficparadise.com/Music/mp3/Hiru_no_Tsuki.mp3">Download this .mp3</A></font></td></tr>
    </table>

<BR>
<BR>
```

AUTOSTART="FALSE" isn't working. The .mp3 starts playing. How do I get it not to autostart?

I want to place more of these on the page. But, I can't if they all start playing at once. I want visitors to have some choices.

Help me please?

Comment: Many issues I see. The `<embed>` tag has not `type attribute`. Also IMHO, the `<embed>` tag is outdated. You could simply use the `<audio>` to run music. Then a table is not for styling purpose. Frankly an audio player is not tabular data. Your style could be done with simle block layout or alternativly with flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use the `<embed>` tag. Use the `<audio>` tag instead. To have controls panel just add the attribute `controls` which is an empty attribute and has no value. Also add a `type attribute`. Audio will not autoplay by default unless you add the `autoplay` attribtue which also is an empty attribute and has no value.

Last but not elast, dont use tables for styling purpose. Its not tabular data. Do the layout design with either `display: block;` or `flexbox`.

Just replace your `<embed>` line with following line:

```
<audio width="295px" height="45px" controls>
  <source src="https://www.fanficparadise.com/Music/mp3/Hiru_no_Tsuki.mp3"  
          type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

```html
    <table width=145 border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5">Mp3 Control Console</font></td></tr>
      <tr><td><audio width="295px" height="45px" controls><source src="https://www.fanficparadise.com/Music/mp3/Hiru_no_Tsuki.mp3"  type="audio/mpeg"></audio></td></tr>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5">Hiru_no_Tsuki.mp3 from Outlaw Star</font></td></tr>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5"><a href="https://www.fanficparadise.com/Music/mp3/Hiru_no_Tsuki.mp3">Download this .mp3</A></font></td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help!^_^

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for helping me!^_^

I have replaced what was there with this now!^_^

```
<BR>
<BR>

<hr>

<BR>

Choose your music while enjoying the images.

<BR>
<BR>

<hr>

<BR>

    <table width=145 border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5">Mp3 Control Console</font></td></tr>
      <tr><td><audio style="width:295px; height:45px;" controls>
<source src="https://www.fanficparadise.com/arielschnee/Music/mp3/Hiru_no_Tsuki.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
</td></tr>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5">Hiru_no_Tsuki.mp3 from Outlaw Star</font></td></tr>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5"><a href="https://www.fanficparadise.com/arielschnee/Music/mp3/Hiru_no_Tsuki.mp3">Download this .mp3</A></font></td></tr>
    </table>

<BR>

<hr>

<BR>

    <table width=145 border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5">Mp3 Control Console</font></td></tr>
      <tr><td><audio style="width:295px; height:45px;" controls>
<source src="https://www.fanficparadise.com/arielschnee/Music/mp3/Blackmore's_Night_-_Ghost_Of_A_Rose.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
</td></tr>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5">Blackmore's_Night_-_Ghost_Of_A_Rose.mp3 from Blackmore's Night</font></td></tr>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5"><a href="https://www.fanficparadise.com/arielschnee/Music/mp3/Blackmore's_Night_-_Ghost_Of_A_Rose.mp3">Download this .mp3</A></font></td></tr>
    </table>

<BR>

<hr>

<BR>

    <table width=145 border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5">Mp3 Control Console</font></td></tr>
      <tr><td><audio style="width:295px; height:45px;" controls>
<source src="https://www.fanficparadise.com/arielschnee/Music/mp3/Shadow_of_the_Moon_-_Blackmore's_Night_(lyrics).mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
</td></tr>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5">Shadow_of_the_Moon_-_Blackmore's_Night_(lyrics).mp3 from Blackmore's Night</font></td></tr>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5"><a href="https://www.fanficparadise.com/arielschnee/Music/mp3/Shadow_of_the_Moon_-_Blackmore's_Night_(lyrics).mp3">Download this .mp3</A></font></td></tr>
    </table>

<BR>

<hr>

<BR>

    <table width=145 border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5">Mp3 Control Console</font></td></tr>
      <tr><td><audio style="width:295px; height:45px;" controls>
<source src="https://www.fanficparadise.com/arielschnee/Music/mp3/Blackmores_Night_Fires_at_Midnight_(with_lyrics).mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
</td></tr>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5">Blackmores_Night_Fires_at_Midnight_(with_lyrics).mp3 from Blackmore's Night</font></td></tr>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5"><a href="https://www.fanficparadise.com/arielschnee/Music/mp3/Blackmores_Night_Fires_at_Midnight_(with_lyrics).mp3">Download this .mp3</A></font></td></tr>
    </table>

<BR>

<hr>

<BR>

    <table width=145 border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5">Mp3 Control Console</font></td></tr>
      <tr><td><audio style="width:295px; height:45px;" controls>
<source src="https://www.fanficparadise.com/arielschnee/Music/mp3/White_Wings.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
</td></tr>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5">White_Wings.mp3 from Breath of Fire II</font></td></tr>
      <tr><td align=center><font face="arial" size="-5"><a href="https://www.fanficparadise.com/arielschnee/Music/mp3/White_Wings.mp3">Download this .mp3</A></font></td></tr>
    </table>

<BR>

<hr>

<BR>
```

If you want to see the page go [url=https://www.fanficparadise.com/index.htm]here[/url].

Enjoy!^_^

Comment: Code only answers are not very useful. Can you edit your answer to explain why you made these changes, and how they solved your problem?

Comment: so you literally used my anwser to solve the issue. If my anwser was the solution, then please mark my anwser as solution and upvote it.

Comment: @tacoshy / Solution mark - - done. Upvote... It won't let me do that now.